# TypeError: (0 , _react.createContext) is not a function on Nextjs using Redux

Tags: redux, next.js, react-redux

im new in using redux and tried to use it with the help of online tutorials. nut im seeing this error:

> Server Error TypeError: (0 , _react.createContext) is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

im providing my codes bellow:
authSlice.js file:

```
    import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper";

const initialState = {
    authState: false,
    userInfo: {},
    authToken: ""
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {

        setAuthState(state, action) {
            state.authState = action.payload
        }
        , setUserInfo(state, action) {
            state.userInfo = action.payload
        },
        setToken(state, action) {
            state.authToken = action.payload
        },
        setAuth(state, action) {
            state.authState = action.payload.authState;
            state.userInfo = action.payload.userInfo;
            state.authToken = action.payload.authToken;
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [HYDRATE]: (state, action) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload.auth
            }
        }
    }
})


export const { setAuthState, setUserInfo, setToken, setAuth } = authSlice.actions
export const selectAuthState = (state) => state.auth.authState;
export const selectAuthToken = (state) => state.auth.authToken;
export const selectUserInfo = (state) => state.auth.userInfo;


export default authSlice.reducer
```

store.js codes:

```
    import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { authSlice } from "./authSlice";
import { createWrapper } from "next-redux-wrapper";

const makeStore = () =>
    configureStore({
        reducer: {
            [authSlice.name]: authSlice.reducer,
        },
        devTools: true,
    });



const store = makeStore()
export default store
```

components where i tried to use redux:

```
    import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import {
    selectAuthState,
    selectAuthToken,
    selectUserInfo,
    setAuthState,
    setUserInfo,
} from "@/data/authSlice";



function Sidebar() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const authState = useSelector(selectAuthState);
    const authToken = useSelector(selectAuthToken)
    const userInfo = useState(selectUserInfo)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!authState) {
            router.push("/")
        }
    }, [router.asPath]);
// rest of the codes
```

```
import axios from "axiosConfig";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  selectAuthState,
  selectAuthToken,
  setAuthState,
  setUserInfo,
} from "@/data/authSlice";

// toastify
// import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
// import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
// const notify = (text) => {
//     toast.success(text , {position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT})
// }

const LoginPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const authState = useSelector(selectAuthState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = authState;
    if (token) {
      router.push("/Dashboard");
    } else {
    }
  }, [router.asPath]);
// rest of the codes
```

i tried to reinstall redux and react-redux but didnt helped.

- also tried Remove the node_modules
- Remove package-lock.json
- `npm install` again.
  but nothing happend.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `"use client"` on top of every file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Every file??  Downvote this please!